# Speedup a Video on Linux

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, arch-linux, mencoder

I don't want to use a player like vlc to speedup the playback. I want to actually speedup playback in the original file; I want the video to be played 2 times faster.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

mencoder has a `-speed` option you can use, e.g. `-speed 2` to double the speed. It's described in the man page. Example:

```
mencoder -speed 2 -o output.avi -ovc lavc input.avi
```

Comment: To make this work I had to add `-oac mp3lame`

Comment: I should add `-srate 8000` too.

Comment: Worth noting that it works with `-ovc copy`, i.e. with no quality loss.

Answer (score 17):

After doing some research on this I found that the following command line option works well with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

- First install ffmpeg.
- `setpts` is for video speed (.5 means twice as fast).
- `atempo` is for audio speed (2 means twice as fast).
- The native FFmpeg AAC encoder used to be considered experimental, but this is no longer the case. If your ffmpeg is old, you will need to add `-strict experimental` to enable this encoder (the console output will mention this if you don't).
- Control video quality and encoding speed with `-crf` and `-preset` as described in [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264). Or just use the defaults if it looks acceptable to you.
- Control audio quality with `-b:a` as described in [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC Audio Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC).

Reference: [FFmpeg Wiki: MP3 Audio Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3).

Comment: I've had the best results with this one. A variation on it: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v libx264 -crf 31 -c:a aac -b:a 64k -movflags +faststart -filter:v "setpts=0.25*PTS" output.mkv`. After ffmpeg was finished I opened it in avidemux and saved it immediately to fix the video duration and remove the audio.

Answer (score 5):

[slowmoVideo](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/index.html) is able to speed up and slow down video

> slowmoVideo is an OpenSource program that creates slow-motion videos
>   from your footage.
>
> But it does not simply make your videos play at 0.01× speed. You can
>   smoothly slow down and speed up your footage, optionally with motion
>   blur.
>
> How does slow motion work? slowmoVideo tries to find out where pixels
>   move in the video (this information is called Optical Flow), and then
>   uses this information to calculate the additional frames.

First [download](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/download.php) and install the program. When it is loaded go to File > New and select your video file.

[image]

With your video loaded draw you curves (by clicking on an empty area) to describe how the video should speed up and slow down.

[image]

When you have finished go to File > Render (Ctrl + R) and choose a directory to save your video

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/) is a video editor for KDE that also can do it and even has a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

openshot is a movie editor in linux. you can download and install it free:  [openshot](https://www.openshot.org/) .

then you must go clip properties and speed tab, then you can change speed of your videos and export them

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.